# Get only Saturday and Sunday dates of month in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Can I find the date of a day that is on which dates the Saturdays and Sundays of a specific month fall? For e.g consider the month of JANUARY-2017. The following dates are weekend days:

```
 7/1/2017 - Saturday
14/1/2017 - Saturday
21/1/2017 - Saturday
28/1/2017 - Saturday 
 1/1/2017 - Sunday
 8/1/2017 - Sunday    
15/1/2017 - Sunday
22/1/2017 - Sunday
29/1/2017 - Sunday
```

I want a SQL Server query for this such that when I pass in month and year as input, I should get back all the above dates (only dates of Saturday and Sunday) as output

I do not wish to use any user defined function and want to finish it in a single `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** As already noted by another user in the comments, this query depends upon your server settings, namely `DATEFIRST`.  If you need alterations to the query because of different settings, just tell me and I can change it around for you.

Using a CTE as dummy data...

```
/* Ignore this part...*/
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT CAST('01/01/2017' AS DATE) AS [Date]
        UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,[Date])
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DATE <= '12/31/2017'
)
/*Your actual SELECT statement would look like this, from your own table of course*/
SELECT 
     [Date]
    ,CASE DATEPART(dw,[Date])
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Saturday'
    END
FROM CTE
WHERE DATEPART(dw,[Date]) IN (1,7)
AND MONTH([Date]) = 12--<month>
AND YEAR([Date]) = 2017--<year>
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) -- You won't need this line if you're querying a real table
;
```

If running that works for you, then your real query would probably look something like this:

```
SELECT 
     [Date]
    ,CASE DATEPART(dw,[Date])
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Saturday'
    END
FROM < the table you want >
WHERE DATEPART(dw,[Date]) IN (1,7) -- Only Sundays and Saturdays
AND MONTH([Date]) = < the month you want >
AND YEAR([Date]) = < the year you want >
;
```

If you want to *generate* the data, then a CTE is the way to go.  If you're passing parameters, it would look something like this:

```
DECLARE
     @MONTH INT
    ,@YEAR INT
;

SET @MONTH = 1;
SET @YEAR = 2017;

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT CAST(CAST(@MONTH AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/01/' + CAST(@YEAR AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [Date]) AS DATE
        UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,[Date])
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DATE <= CAST(@MONTH AS VARCHAR(2)) + 
        CASE 
            WHEN @MONTH IN (9,4,6,11) 
                THEN '/30/'
            WHEN @MONTH IN (1,3,5,7,8,10,12) 
                THEN '/31/'
            WHEN @MONTH = 2 AND @YEAR/4.00 = @YEAR/4 
                THEN '/29/'
            ELSE '/28/'
        END
        + CAST(@YEAR AS VARCHAR(4))
)
SELECT 
     [Date]
    ,CASE DATEPART(dw,[Date])
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Saturday'
    END
FROM CTE
WHERE DATEPART(dw,[Date]) IN (1,7)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
;
```

Comment: This solution rely on the setting of your server, it only works with DATEFIRST 7. If you change datefirst **SET DATEFIRST 1;** It will give a different result.

Comment: That is entirely accurate, and I'll add it to my post.  This is exactly the reason why I provided the original query and asked the user further on in the post if the result was to his liking; if he had responded that this had given an undesired result as you describe, I would have simply updated the query to include his server logic - I can't know ahead of time :) Thank you very much for the constructive addition!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

```
DECLARE @Year AS INT=2017,
@Month AS INT=3,
@FirstDateOfYear DATETIME,
@LastDateOfYear DATETIME

SELECT @FirstDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900, 0)
SELECT @LastDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900 + 1, 0)
-- Creating Query to Prepare Year Data
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 1 AS DayID,
@FirstDateOfYear AS FromDate,
DATENAME(dw, @FirstDateOfYear) AS Dayname
UNION ALL
SELECT cte.DayID + 1 AS DayID,
DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate),
DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate)) AS Dayname
FROM cte
WHERE DATEADD(d,1,cte.FromDate) < @LastDateOfYear
)
SELECT FromDate AS Date, Dayname
FROM CTE
WHERE DayName IN ('Saturday','Sunday') and month(FromDate) = @Month 
OPTION (MaxRecursion 370)
```

Comment: [Copied from here right?](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/29/sql-server-get-date-of-all-weekdays-or-weekends-of-the-year/)

Comment: I think it is nothing wrong if you add source link to your answer. At the moment it looks like you wrote this script...

Comment: @Husen : And this query selects all the date for the entire year and just filtering the saturdays and sundays for the month in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
DECLARE @month date = '2017-01-01'

SET @month = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @month), 0)

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 0 x
  FROM (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) x(n)
),
CTE2 as
(
  SELECT 
    top(day(eomonth(@month))) 
    -- use this syntax for sqlserver 2008
    -- top(datediff(d, @month,dateadd(month,1,@month))) 
    cast(dateadd(d, row_number()over(order by(select 1))-1,@month) as date) cDate
  FROM CTE CROSS JOIN CTE C2
)
SELECT
  cDate, 
  datename(weekday, cDate) Weekday
FROM CTE2
WHERE 
  datediff(d,0,cDate)%7 > 4
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/635024/get-only-saturday-and-sunday-dates-of-month-in-sql-server)**

Comment: Fantastic use of `EOMONTH()`.  Forgot all about that function! Upvoted.

Comment: I really want to know why this was downvoted. As far as i can tell it is by far the best answer in performance and logic. Even alot better than the recursive solution copied from sql authority.

Comment: I certainly can't tell you.  I made my response up out of my head having only a couple of years of experience with SQL, and thus gave a much longer, much less efficient response than you.  Yours is compact and efficient, but maybe more difficult to understand? I would love an explanation of how this bad-boy works... I think it's really impressive.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/finding-the-correct-weekday-regardless-of-datefirst, you simply:

(DATEPART(dw, @your_date) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 NOT BETWEEN 2 AND 6

Answer (score 0):

As requested, single `select`, language neutral, `dateFirst` neutral, almost SQL version neutral:

```
declare @OneDate datetime = '28/01/2017'; -- Any date from the target month/year

select MyDate -- raw date or ...
    -- convert(varchar, MyDate, 103) + ' - ' + dateName(dw, MyDate) -- as Sample
    as WeekEndDate
from (
    select dateAdd(dd, number, dateAdd(mm, dateDiff(mm, 0, @OneDate), 0)) as MyDate
    from master..spt_values
    where type = 'P' and number < 31
    ) j
where 1 + (datePart(dw, MyDate) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 in (6, 7)
    and month(MyDate) = month(@OneDate)
-- order by 1 + (datePart(dw, MyDate) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7, MyDate -- as Sample
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem as follow -

```
DECLARE @MONTH INT,@YEAR INT
SET @MONTH = 1;
SET @YEAR = 2017;

Declare @StartDate date =CAST(CAST(@MONTH AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/01/' + CAST(@YEAR AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [Date]), @EndDate date
Set @EndDate = EOMONTH(@StartDate)

Declare @Temp table (DateOfDay date, DaysName varchar(50))
While(@StartDate <= @EndDate)
Begin

    Insert into @Temp
    SELECT  @StartDate DateOfMonth, 
            case when DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) = 'Saturday' then DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) 
                 when DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' then DATENAME(DW, @StartDate) 
            end DaysName

    set @StartDate = DATEADD(d,1,@StartDate)
End

select * from @Temp where DaysName is not null order by DaysName, DateOfDay
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't you do something like this?

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,'10/11/2016') AS DATE 
WHERE DATE CONTAINS('Saturday') OR DATE CONTAINS('SUNDAY')
```

and instead of '10/11/2016' you only have to figure out how to generate all the dates in a month/year?